shifting sine function
If I want to shift the function $\sin(2x)$ one unit to the right, what is the difference between making $\sin(2(x-1))$ and $\sin(2x-1)$ ? why doesn't the second function make the shift? I'm confused by the difference. Thank you in advance

Shifting any function to the right means substituting $x-1$ in place of every $x$. Doing this with $\sin(2(x))$ produces $\sin(2(x-1))$. Doing this with $f(x)=x^2-2x+7$ for example, results in $f(x-1)=(x-1)^2-2(x-1)+7$ for example. I hope this clears up the confusion.

It is a shift in x, not a shift in 2x.  If you write $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ rather than just $\sin(2x)$ it should be clear.

I'm not sure why this question was voted down. It was an honest question about something which confuses a lot of students.

And as a quick check, $f_1(x) = \sin(2(x-1))$ is zero at $x=1$, one unit to the right of where $f(x) = \sin(2x)$ has $f(0)=0$. But $f_2(x) = \sin(2x-1)$ has $f_2(1) \neq 0$. (Instead, $f_2\left(\frac 12\right) = 0$.)

To shift a function you replace $f(x)$ with $f(x+s)$ where $s$ is the shift to the left (or $-s$ for a shift to the right). In this case you have $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ so $f(x-1) = \sin (2(x-1)) = \sin (2x-2)$. So the difference occurs because $2x-1 \neq 2x-2$.

The easiest way is to picture $green {2(x-1)}$ and $red{2x-1}$
or if you want the old function sin 1 to the right, you have to move every x 1 left.

You should think of $y=\sin(2x)$ as the composition of two functions.
Let $h(x)=\sin(x), g(x)=2x, f(x)=h(g(x))$. Then $f(x)=\sin(2x)$
To shift the graph of a function $c$ units horizontally, replace the $x$ variable with $x-c$. So in order to shift the graph one unit to the right (i.e. +1 units horizontally) replace $x$ with $x-1$.
So $f(x-1)=h(g(x-1))=h(2(x-1))=\sin(2(x-1))$
But
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin(2x-1)&=&\sin\left(2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=&h\left( g\left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=&f\left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
This shifts the graph one-half units to the right.
